# first input[type="text"] not working

Tags: jquery

i want it to set on the `input[type="text"`] but its not working

```
 $("tbody").on("keyup change", "tr td:nth-child(2) input,td:nth-child(3) input,td:nth-child(4) select",
    function () {
        $(this)
        .closest("tr")
        .find("td:first input")// i want it to set on the input[type="text"] but its not working
        .val(this.value);
    });
```

Heres a fiddle :
[fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/yvDDp/10/)

Comment: What problem are you having?  When you type in the text box the button value seems to be updating as well...

Comment: and what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: agree with @entropic the values are updating very well what's your problem is actually!

Comment: You better bind `keyup` and `change` events to `$("tr input[type="text"]` instead of `$("tbody")`

Comment: @entropic, i dont want the button text to update, in eed the first input of type = "text" to be updated

Comment: @Maverick  i need the first input of type = "text" to be updated and not the button

Comment: There is only one textbox on that fiddle - so I still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish... and on top of that, you're not using `input[type="text"]` anywhere either...

Comment: @entropic sorry, i will update it. i should have 2 input field

Comment: So what you're saying is if you select something from the dropdown, or input something in the 2nd textbox, you want the first to update with it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have an issue with your selector if you want to update the first textbox.  Your filter for the event should not contain `tr td:nth-child(2) input` because that is the textbox you are trying to change.

Second, the first td doesn't contain a textbox at all - it contains the button.  This is what you are searching for when your selector is `td:first input`.  If you want to find the first instance of a textbox, your search string should be `.find("input[type='text']:first")`.

The updated event looks like this:

```js
$("tbody").on("keyup change", "td:nth-child(3) input,td:nth-child(4) select",
    function () {
        $(this) //input
        .closest("tr") //finds the row associated with the input
        .find("input[type='text']:first") //returns the text input
        .val(this.value); //sets the text
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvDDp/12/

Comment: wow,thans for valuable information! Anyways, I know its too much, but i want to alert the `first input[type=text]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "alert the first input[type=text]".

Comment: I mean i want the text or value to see using `alert()`

Comment: another wow, because im thinking of something like .Text or .Value

Comment: hmmm,is there anyway i can stop the next event to trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
.find("td:first input")
```

To:

```
.find("td input[type=text]")
```

It's in the second td, so it won't work with `td:first`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way.
I'm not sure why you are selecting the text boxes in complicated way. Unless you have some reason for doing it that way, I'd recommend doing the same thing in a simpler way as follows.

```
$("td:nth-child(3) input").on("keyup change",function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().find("input").val($(this).val());
});
```

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvDDp/14/)

Comment: if i add another input text field, the first input doesnt update sir @Maverick